# Listing subcategories on main category page

Tags: magento2

I want to list subcageroeis on main category page under category description.
I found this article but it's not working on Magento 2:https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-listing-sub-categories-on-a-category-page.html

Comment: Please find the link this may help https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125939/magento-2-get-subcategories-of-specific-parent-category

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: Can You Post the code which you have executed.

Comment: Im getting error on line 5

Comment: It must working in this way https://www.creare.co.uk/blog/magento/magento-subcategories-category-pages

Comment: @Efex that tutorial is for Magento 1 and this question is about Magento 2