# How to get all the Children Categories IDs of the Specific Category in Magento2

Tags: magento2, category, frontend, category-products

I want to get all categories of the specific category for that I tried

```
public function categoryHide()
    {
        $data = $this->arrayData();
        $save = array();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of Object Manager
        $categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');// Instance of Category Model
        foreach($data as $test)
        {
            $category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($test);
            // $parentCategories = $category->getParentCategories();
            $childrenCategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
            foreach ($childrenCategories as $cat){
                $save[] = $cat->getId();
              }
        }
        return array_merge($data,$save);   
    }

}
```

This code is working perfectly for the **Gear** but if we tried to get the Ids of the **Women** or **men** category it will return only 2 children
[image]

it will only return the ids of **tops** and **bottoms** not there further children eg for women its category is **20** and tops category is **21** and bottoms category is **22** its only return there values not further children of tops and bottom. now I want to get all the child categories ids. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125939/magento-2-get-subcategories-of-specific-parent-category/358176#358176

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you will have to solve this with recursion.

`$category->getChildrenCategories()` will only return direct children

```
public function categoryHide()
    {
        $data = $this->arrayData();
        $save = array();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of Object Manager
        $categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');// Instance of Category Model
        foreach($data as $test)
        {
            $category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($test);
            addToSave($category, $save);
        }
        return array_merge($data,$save);   
    }

}

public function addToSave($category, &$save)
{
    $childrenCategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
    foreach ($childrenCategories as $cat){
        $save[] = $cat->getId();
        addToSave($cat, $save);
    }
}
```

Comment: can u please help me how to solve this?

Comment: @AsadKhan see updated answer for code. I did not verify if this works

Answer (score 3):

```
$category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($id);
$category->getAllChildren(false) - will return comma separated list of ids
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code :

```
<?php 
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of Object Manager
 $categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');// Instance of Category Model
 $categoryId = 15; // YOUR CATEGORY ID
 $category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
 // Children  Categories
 $childrenCategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();

?>
```

Get all level subcategories :

```
<?php

function categoryLoop($id){
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $categories = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($id);

    if($categories->hasChildren()){
    echo "<ul>";
        $subcategories = explode(',', $categories->getChildren());
        foreach ($subcategories as $category) {
            $subcategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);
            echo "<li>";
            echo $subcategory->getName();
            echo "</li>";
            //echo "<br>";
            if($subcategory->hasChildren()){ categoryLoop($category); }
        }
    echo "</ul>";
    }
}

categoryLoop(2);  // enter your category id here
```

Comment: it only return direct children not all the child... I want to get all the children

Comment: @AsadKhan, I edited my answer please check it now