# How to sort the subcategories of specific parent category in magento 2.3 programatically

Tags: category, magento2.3.1, sub-categories

I have the parent category "XXX" and having around 115 subcategories under the same.

I am trying to sort the subcategories listed under of specific parent category at the backend...
[image]

Comment: reference = > https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125939/magento-2-get-subcategories-of-specific-parent-category

Comment: Please mention what is your complete requirement..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use like below.

```
protected $_categoryCollection;

public function __construct(
 \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
 \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollection,
  array $data = []
 )
{
   $this->_categoryCollection = $categoryCollection;
   parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
public function getCategoryCollection()
 {
   $categoryId = "your parent categoryId";
    $collection = $this->_categoryCollection->create()->load($categoryId)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc');
    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: in which file should I use.. or its a custom code?

Comment: @rohan.katkar, what is your exact requirement? you want to get all sub categories for parent category with sort? or to swap the admin categories programmatically?

Comment: to sort the all sub categories for spefic parent category...

Comment: @rohan.katkar, sort with what and where? you want retrieve the collection?

Comment: jafar, I am trying to sort subcategories of particular parent category.. my concern is just that where should I fix this... in core or as custom... looking at your code... it seems good.. but where to place it... getCategoryCollection() is defined in core...

Comment: @rohan.katkar, the code i written will sort the categories of parent category with position and give you the collection, is what you are looking for? or something else, what you need exactly, please brief it, sort means with what u want to sort and where?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94045/discussion-between-rohan-katkar-and-jafar-pinjar).