# How to get Sub category names of a particular Parent category in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, sub-categories

I want to fetch Sub categories name of a particular Parent category using Parent category Id.
Please note, i dont want to use Object manager directly in phtml file.
I am using block to write function.

Comment: please check this link, I hope it will be helpful in your case https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125939/magento-2-get-subcategories-of-specific-parent-category

Comment: @HiteshBalpande As already mentioned. i dont want to use Object manager

Comment: please check 4th answers in above link Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory they used CategoryFactory  not objectmanager

Comment: @HiteshBalpande I tried that , it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can try using category model:

**Code for block file**

```
......
protected $_categoryFactory;
......

public function __construct(
.....
\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
.....
) {
        ......
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        ......
}

public function getSubCatNameById($catId) {
        $categoryName = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($catId)->getName();
        return $categoryName;
}
```

**Code for phtml file**

```
$catId = 2;  //2 is your category id

echo $block->getSubCatNameById($catId);
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Does this return child category name?

Comment: @Nafisa yes, by using this you can get the category name.

Comment: Shiekh ......... In your code, no where it is mentioned about child category. your code will return parent category name.

Comment: @Nafisa updated, you can check now.

Comment: Have you tried this code? and checked what does it return? I want to use Parent category id to get child category name

Comment: @Nafisa Yes I checked it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103074/discussion-between-nafisa-and-faisal-sheikh).

Answer (score 0):

> Please copy this code in your custom module block function, I hope it
>   will be helpful for you.

```
   protected $categoryFactory;

   public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
    ) {
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    }


    public function getSubCategories() {
        $_category = $this->categoryFactory->create();
        $catId = 12;    // your parent category name
        $category = $_category->load($catId);

        $collection = $category->getCollection()
                ->addIsActiveFilter()
                ->addOrderField('name')
                ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren());
        return $collection;   //Get subcategory collection of parent category


    }
```

> call above function in your phtml file like this:

```
    $subCategories= $block->getSubCategories();

    foreach($subCategories as $subCats):
            echo $subCats->getName();
    endforeach:
```

Comment: How to print sub categpry name in phtml file then?

Comment: please check my updated answer.

Comment: getting this error Recoverable Error: Object of class Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Category\\Collection could not be converted to string

Comment: okay you need to debug the $subCategories = $block->getSubCategories(); print_r($subCategories);exit; in your phtml file before foreach loop

Comment: Hi @Nafisa, can you please accept the answer if code is worked for you.