# Show parent categories on a page

Tags: magento2, catalog, cms-block, cms-pages

I am a beginner in Magento. This may be a simple question.

I have a header menu 'shop'. This link should redirect to a page that shows all parent categories. How can I do this? any help is really appreciated.

This is how the 'shop' page should looks like (Parent categories only).

[image: This what I need]

Thank you.

Comment: Yes I can help you.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I do this ?

Comment: you can see here..https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/300734/how-to-get-sub-category-names-of-a-particular-parent-category-in-magento-2-3/300738?noredirect=1#comment433643_300738 Hope my answer will help you!

Comment: Could you please tell me how to set the phtml file ? I am totally confused with the magento workflow

Comment: yes so in which page you need all display

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel I have a menu 'Shop' in the header, so on clicking this menu, I should redirect to a page which shows all parent categories only.

Comment: for a particular category? like if the test is the category? and it has 2 subcategories and that 2 subcategories have also subcategories. so you want N level or only 1 level?

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel I updated the question could you please have a look.

Comment: ok I will give you a code for that page wait.

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel Thank you very much

Comment: @Sayanth add answer please check it. you need to add other fields.

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel I will try your answer. Btw can you please help me here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301731/block-is-not-getting-called-in-custom-module-magento-2-3

Comment: you need to put this in your category .phtml file otherwise not works my solutions

Comment: @Sayanth I have updated my code, now you can try my solution.

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel Please let me know how can I use your code in the last question I asked

Comment: @FaisalSheikh Thank you faisal, I will try your code and let you know.

Comment: @Sayanth Brother if solution work, please upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

first you create a category source file inside Model:

Note: Here root categories are excluded.

path: Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Source\Categories.php

**Categories.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Source;

class Categories implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface {

    protected $_categoryFactory;
    protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
       \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function getCategoryCollection($isActive = true, $level = false, $sortBy = false, $pageSize = false, $excludeLevel = false) {
        $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        // select only active categories
        if ($isActive) {
            $collection->addIsActiveFilter();
        }

        // select categories of certain level
        if ($level) {
            $collection->addLevelFilter($level);
        }

        // sort categories by some value
        if ($sortBy) {
            $collection->addOrderField($sortBy);
        }

        // select certain number of categories
        if ($pageSize) {
            $collection->setPageSize($pageSize);
        }

        $this->excludeRootCategories($collection, $excludeLevel);

        return $collection;
    }

    public function toOptionArray() {
        return $arr = $this->_toArray();
    }

    private function _toArray() {
        $categories = $this->getCategoryCollection(false, false, false, false);

        $catagoryList = array();
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $catagoryList[] = ['label' => __($this->_getParentName($category->getPath()) . $category->getName()), 'value' => $category->getEntityId()];
        }

        return $catagoryList;
    }

    private function _getParentName($path = '') {
        $parentName = '';
        $rootCats = array(1, 2);

        $catTree = explode("/", $path);
        // Deleting category itself
        array_pop($catTree);

        if ($catTree && (count($catTree) > count($rootCats))) {
            foreach ($catTree as $catId) {
                if (!in_array($catId, $rootCats)) {
                    $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($catId);
                    $categoryName = $category->getName();
                    $parentName .= $categoryName . ' -> ';
                }
            }
        }

        return $parentName;
    }

    public function excludeRootCategories($collection, $excludeLevel) {
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('level', ['gteq' => $excludeLevel]);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getCategoriesOptionsArray() {
        $categories = $this->getCategoryCollection(true, 2, false, false, 2);

        $catagoryList = array();
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $catagoryList[] = ['label' => __($this->_getParentName($category->getPath()) . $category->getName()), 'value' => $category->getEntityId()];
        }

        return $catagoryList;
    }

}
```

Now you need to call the categories model class in your **block** file:

```
.........
protected $_categoriesSource;
.........

public function __construct(
        ..........
        \Vendor\ModuleNAme\Model\Source\Categories $categoriesSource, 
        ..........
) {
    ......
    $this->_categoriesSource = $categoriesSource;
    ......
}

public function getParentCategoryOptions() {
    return $this->_categoriesSource->getCategoriesOptionsArray();
}
```

finally, you can get the lists of all parent categories in **phtml** file:

```
$categoryOptions = $block->getParentCategoryOptions();
echo '<pre>';
print_r(categoryOptions);
```

Hope, this solution will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        


$categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$categoryHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category');
$categoryRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository');

$categoryId = 3; // YOUR CATEGORY ID
$category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);

//var_dump($category->getData());

$parentCategories = $category->getParentCategories();
$childrenCategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
$subcats = $childrenCategories->getData();

foreach ($childrenCategories as $cat) {
    echo $cat->getName();
    echo "<br>";
}
```

and then use it in your .phtml file.
Hope it works!