# Code reviewed Magento Suggestion

Tags: magento2

below shows that the code contain method get_categories that reload the category by ID after loading the category collection.

```
    public function  get_categories($categories) 
{ //This is the recursive function created and here we pass the a collection of categories.
  //$array is a variable to store all the category detail .
    $array = array();
    foreach($categories as $category) {

            $cat = $this->getCategoryModel()->load($category->getId());
            $array[$category->getLevel()][$cat->getId()]= array('id' => $cat->getId(), 'level' => $cat->getLevel(), 'name' => $cat->getName(), 'url' => $cat->getUrl(), 'display_mode' => $cat->getDisplayMode(), 'image' => $cat->getImageUrl('wizard_icon'), 'description' => $cat->getWizardQuestion(), 'categories' => [] ); //In this line we get an a link for the product and product count of that category
            if($category->hasChildren()) {  //if category has children or not. If yes then it proceed in inside loop.
                 $children = $category->getChildrenCategories(); // $children get a list of all subcategories
                $array[$category->getLevel()][$cat->getId()]['categories']=  $this->get_categories($children); //recursive call the get_categories function again.
                }

        }
    return  $array;
}
```

how can i do other way need guidance .

Comment: I didn't understand your question can you give me more explanation? As I notice you're loading a category id & then getting the children categories that you want?

Comment: i wrote this code but its causes multiple queries instead of one and negatively affects site performance.

Comment: From which source you're calling this function? phtml or any block ?

Comment: yup this is block and i am using in phtml file  $categoryTreeModel = $this->get_categories($types);

Comment: you can use the node tree of the categories, it will faster and more powerful. You can check it here:  vendor/magento/module-theme/Block/Html/Topmenu.php

Comment: I think it's helps you : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125939/magento-2-get-subcategories-of-specific-parent-category

Comment: actually i am selecting category on behalf of selection can you come private message