# Get child categories tree when Flat Catalog Category is enabled in admin in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, category-tree, flat-catalog

> How to get child categories from selected parent category when "Use
>   Flat Catalog Category" is enabled?

I need to create a small menu which displays all sub-categories of current category in a custom menu.

To get sub-categories of the current category, I extended class `Magento\Catalog\Block\Navigation` and created a method which returns sub-categories (identifier of the current category is passed in `$parent` parameter):

```
namespace Company\MyNav\Block;
class MyNav extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Navigation
{
    public function getCategoryChildren($parent)
    {
        $category = ObjectManager::getInstance()->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category');
        $subCategories = $category->getCategories($parent);
        return $subCategories;
    }
    // ...
}
```

It all works great, method `getCategories` from `Magento\Catalog\Model\Category` returns all sub-categories (also from all lower levels) of the selected parent category.

But as soon as I enable "Use Flat Catalog Category" option in admin, method `getCategories` returns **entire tree of categories** instead of only the children of the selected category.

1. **Shouldn't the same code give the same results no matter if flat categories are enabled or disabled**? Is this a bug in Magento 2?
2. Are there any additional steps needed to make this code work even flat categories field is enabled?

Comment: it might be helpful http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101493/magento-2-display-sub-category-of-parent

Comment: Have you fixed it your issue? You have to just keep block inside your any category page. After keeping this your category and subcategory will display. This is tested in 2.1 version

Comment: @ zitix any update on this  bounty question ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `getChildren` to get child category data in your block even `Use Flat Catalog Category` is enabled.

For example

```
namespace Custom\Module\Block\World;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_categoryFactory;
    protected $_category;
    protected $_categoryHelper;
    protected $_categoryRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;        
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
        /**
     * Get category object
     * Using $_categoryFactory
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
     */
    public function getCategory($categoryId) 
    {
        $this->_category = $this->_categoryFactory->create();
        $this->_category->load($categoryId);        
        return $this->_category;
    }


    /**
     * Retrieve children ids comma separated
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getChildren($categoryId = false)
    {
        if ($this->_category) {
            return $this->_category->getChildren();
        } else {
            return $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getChildren();
        }        
    }  



}
```

Inside the phtml template.

```
$test =  $block->getChildren('20');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($test);
```

Out put

[image]

Reference [link](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-parent-category-children-categories-product-count/) for more details.

Recommended to pass classes to constructor as a dependency.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You have use `CategoryRepository` for getting all categories with sub-categories.

```
$parentCatId = 1;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categoryRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository');
$parentcategories = $categoryRepository->get($parentCatId);
$categories = $parentcategories->getChildrenCategories();
foreach($categories as $category){
     $ChildCategoryValue[] = ['label' => $category->getName(), 'value' => $category->getId()];
}
return $ChildCategoryValue;
```

May be it will help you, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is used when **flat_category** enable from admin with current category get child category.

**app/code/Test/Categorytree/view/frontend/templates/listing.phtml**

```
<?php
    $currentCategory = $this->getCurrentCategoryInfo();
    $noOfCategory  = count($currentCategory);
?>
<?php if($noOfCategory) { ?>
<ul class="listing-category-manual">
<?php
    foreach($currentCategory as $categoryDetails){
        $categoryId = $categoryDetails->getId();
        $categoryObj = $this->getCategoryData($categoryId); 
        $categoryUrl = $categoryObj->getUrl();
        $categoryName = $categoryDetails->getName();        
 ?>
     <li class="listing-item">
            <div class="product details product-item-details">
                <a href="<?php echo $categoryUrl; ?>">       
                    <div class="listing-category-info">
                        <span class="category-name"><?php echo $categoryName; ?></span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <?php 
                $getSubCategory = $this->subCategory($categoryObj->getId());
                if(count($getSubCategory) > 0){
            ?>
                    <ul>
                    <?php foreach($getSubCategory as $subcat){  
                            $subId = $subcat['entity_id'];
                            $subcategoryObj = $this->getCategoryData($subId);
                            $categoryUrl = $subcategoryObj->getUrl();
                            $categoryName = $subcategoryObj->getName();
                    ?>
                    <li>
                       <a href="<?php echo $categoryUrl; ?>">  
                        <div class="listing-category-info">
                            <span class="category-name"><?php echo $categoryName; ?></span>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </ul>
            <?php } ?>
    </li> 
<?php   } //endforeach ?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

**app/code/Test/Categorytree/Block/Subcategory.php**

```
<?php
namespace Test\Categorytree\Block;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Subcategory extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $categoryFactory;
    protected $layerResolver;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,  
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;   
        $this->_catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $data
        );
    }

    public function getCurrentCategoryInfo(){
        $categories = $this->_catalogLayer->getCurrentCategory()->getChildrenCategories();
        return $categories;
    }

    public function getCategoryData($id){
        return $category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($id);       
    }

    public function subCategory($id){
        $category = $this->getCategoryData($id);
        $childs = $category->getChildrenCategories();
        foreach($childs as $child){
            $subchild[] = $child->getData();
        }
        return $subchild;
    }
}
```

**Define inside static block below code,**

```
{{block class="Test\Categorytree\Block\Subcategory" template="Test_Categorytree::listing.phtml"}}</p>
```

call static block in your category from backend.
**Go to Category**

Content Tab,

```
Content -> Add CMS Block set your cms block.
```

Display settings Tab:
**select Display mode value as static block only from dropdown.**

Answer (score 0):

In `Magento 1.x` we can achieve the same thing with the help of **recursive function**. If you want to create menu in tree structure you have to use the same logic to achieve that.

So in `Magento 2.x` you can use the same logic of **recursive function** to achieve this thing with the help of Magento 2.x code.

```
$websiteRoorCategory = 2; // You have to set website root category id here
$ChildCategoryValue = getCategory($websiteRoorCategory);
echo '<pre>';print_r($ChildCategoryValue);


function getCategory($parentCatId)
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Call object manager from class object
    $categoryRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository');
    $parentcategories = $categoryRepository->get($parentCatId);
    $categories = $parentcategories->getChildrenCategories();
    $i=0;
    foreach($categories as $category){
        $ChildCategoryValue[$i] = ['label' => $category->getName(), 'value' => $category->getId()];
        $childCat = getCategory($category->getId());
        if($childCat){
            $ChildCategoryValue[$i]['child'] = $childCat;
        }   
    $i++;
    }

    return $ChildCategoryValue;

}
```