# Magento 2 Log Bundle Product Data in List Page?

Tags: magento2, product, log, bundle-product, list.phtml

How to Log Bundle Product Data (Print Product complete information)In Default Product list.phtml file in magento 2.I am Getting

```
 foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):
```

When I write

```
echo $_product->getProductUrl()
```

It is displaying correct product url.But When I tried to print the Entire Product Data by using

```
print_r($_product->getData());
```

It is showing Blank Page I changed memory size but again showing blank page only (**It is a bundle product**) So atleast I want to Log that data in some **test.log** file for that I used

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info(print_r($_product->getData()), true);
```

but the **test.log** file is empty.Can anyone Help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like as well you can use this to pass data in to log.

```
        <?php
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r(json_encode($_product->getData()));
        exit;
        ?>
```

Comment: thank you Krishna..It is printing product data but it is a bundle product na so i need bundled items also.Here Bundle Items are not showing.How to get Bundle items also like this way..?

Comment: You can refer this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139920/get-child-categories-tree-when-flat-catalog-category-is-enabled-in-admin-in-mage/142500#142500

Comment: definitely I will accept if it works :)